# Testing for an SDK in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am creating a universal windows application which will be used on both desktop, and mobile devices. The mobile devices will use vibration API.

```
//Vibrate the device
VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
```

I have added the necessary extension to the project to allow for this:

[image: Project reference extensions]

The **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP** will of course, not be present on desktop machines, therefore I need to *conditionally* test to check whether the SDK is available so I can execute the `Vibrate` method.

Essentially, if the app is running on the desktop, I do not want to execute the `Vibrate` method, otherwise I'll receive the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Encore.Scanner.UI.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Requested Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification.VibrationDevice' is not registered.

Is there a way I can check whether the SDK is available? Something like this:

```
if (...windows mobile extension is present)
{
    //Vibrate the device.    
    VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I needed. Here's how I achieved this if anyone stumbles across this problem in future.

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification.VibrationDevice"))
{
    ...
```

Comment: This is helpful! However As part of the universal app framework if this vibration code was run on a non suitable device then would it crash? Surely it would just ignore the action?

Comment: @Harvey It would probably be worth doing a null check on `VibrationDevice.GetDefault()`. Just in case.

Comment: Okay, I'll bare this in mind as I would probably never have taken this approach. Thanks again!

Comment: This is the documented recommended way to do things: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx#writing_code . It will ensure the VibrationDevice type is present and can be called, but like Mike says you'll still want to make check that the calls succeed.

Comment: @MikeEason - Are you sure the null check on `VibrationDevice.GetDefault()` is necessary? If you call `GetDefault()` on desktop, it crashes with `System.TypeLoadException`. So I think it might be safe to assume that if it doesn't crash, then vibration is available.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT - I couldn't find anything related to vibration in the article you linked, it might have changed in the last few years.

Comment: Also I just tested on the Windows Phone Emulator. It reports that Vibration is available, but calling vibrate doesn't do anything. So I don't think the null check is necessary.